# Using Angular, click a button to change a DOM element and then run a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Inside my Angular app, I want to, on the click of a button run a function - which I am currently doing with:

```
(click)="generate(feedIn.value)"
```

This function can take a little while to run, so I would like to display a progress bar whilst the function runs, specifically a progress bar from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview). The progress bar has multiple states but I figured I can use:

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="{{progress}}" value="0"></mat-progress-bar>
```

and changing `this.progress` inside the component class whilst the function is running. Eg while running `this.progress = "indeterminate"` and when not running `this.progress = "determinate"`, the latter with `value="0"' appears as a static, empty progress bar which suits what I was looking for.

The issue as I understand is that as soon as I run the function, the app is busy running the function and will not update the DOM until the function has finished processing, so something like:

```
(click)="progress='indeterminate'; generate(feedIn.value); progress='determinate';"
```

won't work (as far as I know).

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem - I'm very new to Angular and web-dev technologies in general so I'm sure there is a simple solution, but any help would be great!

Edit:
I also calling to another function `(click)="run(feedIn.value)"` which looks like:

```
async run(text: string) {
    this.progress = "indeterminate";
    this.text = await this.generate(text);
}
```

With `this.progress = "determinate";` at the end of the `generate` function.

Thanks!

Edit 2:
The `generate` function looks like this (it's very messy at the moment).

```js
  async generate(text: string) {
    // check if the user has changed the text and if so reset model state
    if (this.text != text) this.model.resetStates();
    this.text = text;  // update class text
    text = (text.length > 100) ? (text.slice(text.length-100, text.length)) : (text);  // slice long text

    let y_hat: tf.Tensor  // initialize variables we will be using
    let yTypeArray: Iterable<unknown>;
    let yArray: object;
    let yIdx: number;
    let textPreds: string = "";

    // converting start string to numbers (vectorisation/embedding)
    const idxArray = getNum(this.char2idx, text);

    // iterate through producing 100 predictions (characters)
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length + 100; i++) {
      if (i < text.length) {
        // for the length of the text, we are just passing the user input
        this.inputTensor = tf.expandDims([idxArray[i]], 0);  // convert array to compatible tensor
      };

      y_hat = this.model.predict(this.inputTensor);  // make model prediction

      y_hat = tf.squeeze(y_hat, [0]);  // reformat tensor dimensions
      yTypeArray = y_hat.dataSync();  // convert tensor to JS TypeArray
      yArray = Array.from(yTypeArray);  // convert TypeArray to normal Array
      // take index of max value in array (character index with highest probability)
      yIdx = indexOfMax(yArray);
      // prepare prediction as input to next iteration
      this.inputTensor = tf.expandDims([yIdx], 0);

      if (i >= text.length - 1) {
        // append prediction as input to next iteration
        textPreds = textPreds.concat(this.idx2char[yIdx]);
      };
    };
    return textPreds;
  };
```

Comment: Why not call a single function on click that does those 3 statements? If a function is blocking the UI then you can try converting it into an asynchronous function and await it.

Comment: Can you post the code of function. You might need async approach.

Comment: `mode="{{progress}}"` is angularJS notation. Since you're using angular, try using `[mode]="progress"` for a one-way binding, or `[(mode)]="progress"` for a two-way binding

Comment: @jegtugado yes I tried doing this, I've updated my question with what I did (under Edit), maybe I implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: @Arun205 it's a long and very messy function at the moment, but I've included it at the end

Comment: @Pieterjan thanks! I will update

Comment: Convert `generate(text)` to return a promise. You can google up async-await in javascript. On your `async run(text)` you will have to `await this.generate(text);`. Awaiting asynchronous functions will allow the code to run without blocking the UI. Goodluck.

Comment: You might have to use change detection as well to update DOM.

Comment: @jegtugado thanks! I've been trying to implement it (I updated the code above), and I am returning a promise from generate now, but the code still seems to be stopping on that line, letting it process, before continuing, I assume I must be implementing async-await incorrectly?

Comment: @Arun205 thanks! I've added @Input() to the definition of this.text - I think this is right